# Git does not recognize/list the branches of my repo

Tags: git, github, terminal

I have a project with two branches yet. Now I created a third branch and I want to push code from new folder in it. I started with `git init` then `git clone ssh-adress` so I'm actually connected to my project. But now I want to show the branches from the project with `git branch --list` or swith the branch `git checkout name`. But I either get just nothing with the list or I get this error when trying to switch the branch:

> error: pathspec 'name' did not match any file(s) known to git.

So Im wondering why that is since I am obviously connected to my project path. Did I miss a command or something?

Comment: What do you mean you did git init *and* git clone? Are you trying to create a new repo or create a new local copy of the existing one? What does `git branch -la` say?

Comment: I have a repo with three braches(master,v2,v3) every one of them I have in separate a folder. Now I created the v3 branch in gitlab. I just init the folder and connect it with clone to my repo. I want push my third folder code to this V3 branch but somehow I can't reach the branches from the terminal. All branches are in one repo. `git branch -la` is empty output.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. You don't have to have a folder per branch, you can switch branches within one local copy, and you don't need to init a folder before cloning to it. In fact you may have cloned your remote repo *into* a separate local repo, and you're looking at the branches of the new local repo not the clone.

Comment: Ok. The thing is that it actually works for master and v2, so I don't get why it suddenly doesn't. So what should I do? Create a new folder, clone first and then init?

Comment: Presumably you did those differently. If you really must have a folder per branch (again, this is not necessary) you simply need to `git clone <link> <directory>` - the directory does not have to be init'd (or even exist).

Answer (score 0):

(This has been discussed lightly in the comments.)

To get a repo from one location to another, use `git clone`. You do not need `git init` (although it is harmless to run in an existing repo).

By itself, in a non-repo, `git init` will create a new one. So `init`ing before `clone`ing will be wrong.

Lastly, clones don’t pull all branches from a remote (typically just one). To fetch others, you need a form of checkout.